# Вывод сообщения в консоль по времени на js

Tags: javascript, jquery, консоль

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы строка

```
document.log("Прошла секунда");
```

выводилась через каждую секунду. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую функцию использовать? Пробовал так:

```
function second_passed() {
    alert("Прошла секунда")
}
setTimeout(second_passed, 1000);
```

но не работает. Один раз срабатывает и всё.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем примере функция `second_passed()` срабатывает через секунду, и всё. В теле функции требуется вызвать её ещё раз.

```
  function sec() {
       console.log("Прошла секунда");
       setTimeout(sec, 1000);
    }
    setTimeout(sec, 1000);
```

Также можно решить Вашу задачу и с помощью [setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval), который в отличии от `setTimeout` выполняется повторно, через указанный промежуток времени.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    console.log("Прошла секунда");   
}, 1000);
```